# How to list LLDB variables in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I want to list the lldb variables in Xcode debugger
such as

```
$0 = ...

$1 = ...
```

Which command should i enter?

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzeAy.png)

Comment: I guess we can't.

Comment: you should refer [About LLDB and Debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/lldb-guide/chapters/Introduction.html) and [LLDB Official website](http://lldb.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [frameVariable](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/lldb-guide/chapters/C5-Examining-The-Call-Stack.html) to get a list of all variables in the stack frame.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSHashTable *hashTable = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];
    ABC *object = [[ABC alloc] init];
    [hashTable addObject:object];
    //NSLog(@"%@", [hashTable anyObject]);
    object = nil;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
}
```

**frame variable**

```
(ViewController *) self = 0x00007fa2275047d0
(SEL) _cmd = "viewDidLoad"
(NSConcreteHashTable *) hashTable = 0x000061000013f5e0
(ABC *) object = nil
(int) i = 0
(int) j = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to list all the variables you have defined in or are the result of expressions you've evaluated, right?

If so, there isn't a way to do that currently.  But it would be straightforward to add.  Please file an enhancement request with the lldb bug reporter:

https://bugs.llvm.org

and somebody will get to it.